# Biztalk SQL Adapter or a .NET SqlClient

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

My application has BizTalk orchestration which needs to do basic insert into a table. Which is the better way of doing it

- using a SQL adapter that calls the stored procedure(with just one insert statement) on SQL server
- including a method call on orchestration where the method uses the SQLclient.SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method with the SQLstored procedure on the GetCommand.

I want to know the best way of inserting the data into a database in the BizTalk orchestration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always prefer using the SQL Adapter.

1. It will be tracked in the Group Hub
2. You'll get better diagnostics and tracking options around the port
3. Retry logic is built in and configurable

The biggest downside is performance - it will create another persistence point in your orchestration on the send shape, whereas an inline SQL call would avoid that.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. That answers my question.In my case, I don't need any tracking and retry logic and performance is key since lot of orchestrations will be running at same time

Comment: Just keep in mind then that deadlocking may occur when multiple orchestrations try to insert - and that you won't get the retry or logging around that you'd otherwise get.  You may find records are missing and not have a good way to check why

Comment: NO!  Do not use the SQLClient in code!  *Do not make any guess about performance.  It'll probably be wrong. :)*  Trust me, you will create more problems for you and future support of the app.

Comment: One mistake in connection handling will cost you more than the Persistence Point.  Use the SQL Adapter.

Comment: Haha so did you down vote me for telling him to use the SQL adapter @Johns-305?  Little confused.

Comment: @DanField Yes, it was me.  Why?  It seems the OP decided to use the SQL Client because of the, unfortunate mention of 'performance'.  I frequently warn to never make guesses on performance since without knowing what to address, if you even need to, things will just get worse.  For that one reason, I consider this an unadvisable Answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The **correct and best** way to integrate with SQL Server in a BizTalk app is with the **WCF SQL-Adapter**.

Do not use the SQL Client in code since you have a greater chance of making things worse, operations, maintenance and performance, over using the built in tools.

Never guess or make assumptions about performance since without knowing *exactly* what to address, *through test and measurement*, you will either A) Spend time 'fixing' a problem that doesn't exist or B) make things worse by implementing something less optimized than the base product or C) both.

Use the WCF-SQL Adapter and if you measure a specific gap with an SLA, let us know, we can help you with that.  99.99%, the solution will not involve using the SQL Client directly.